# Behaviour tree editor Unity

Tags: unity

I'm a programmer, so I am perfectly aware of how to implement a behaviour tree. I don't want to rely on third party tools, but still have convenient tools for creating the AI for my game.

I was looking at tools like [this one](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/20280) but I could not find out how to create editor extensions like that in Unity.

I also noticed that there is a new experimental feature ([Playables](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Experimental.Director.Playable.html)) in the current versions of Unity.
Does this use the state machine editor from the Animator? Should/Could I use that to implement a behaviour tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general topic you're interested in is editor scripting.

Here's Unity's start page for it:
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExtendingTheEditor.html

Here's a tutorial they put together as well:
https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/editor-scripting-intro

Neither of those links deal directly with making a node based editor, which is likely what you want to do.  I recommend you check them out though, as they'll give you some basics on extending the editor in general, which you'll need as a starting point.

Once you're familiar with the basics of editor scripting, you may find this useful:
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/simple-node-editor.189230/